# Regex Grouping - Matching / Not Matching occurrences

Tags: regex, vb.net

I was practicing my regex groups in VB.Net while reading my new cookbook and wondered if it's possible to group One set of chars, numbers or what ever the desired match should be into One group and what ever else does not match into another. Keep in mind this is only for fun and about me learning. Example string i will match.

HelloWorld123

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub foo()
    Dim text = "HelloWorld123"
    Dim m = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?i)[a-z]").Matches(text)

End Sub
End Class
```

So now all the letters are in group 0, thats fine but how can i list ANY thing else into group 1 thats not in group 0? A better example would be say i had a list of chars !"£ that i wanted in group 0 and any thing else in group 1, the only way i could possible think and thats not saying this would work is duplication. ([!""£])([^!""£]) not saying thats valid but my concern is if this lists grows so does the duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could negate the character class, e.g. `[^a-z]` will match any character *except* `a` through `z`, and then use an alternation (`|`) to capture them separately:

```
Dim m = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?i)[a-z]|([^a-z])").Matches(text)
```

But for that matter, you could just match any character (`.`) like this:

```
Dim m = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?i)[a-z]|(.)").Matches(text)
```

Here, anything that's not matched by the first pattern, `[a-z]`, will be matched by the second pattern, `.`, and captured in group 1. This works because the regex engine will attempt to find matches starting from the first pattern on the left of the alternation, then moving to the right.